# Release IOS app for only specified client group

Tags: ios, release, appstore-approval

My team is developing an IOS app which is to be used by specified users who are the customer of our hardware product(sensors being used in manufacturing).

Can I release this app through normal Apple APP approval procedure and adopted by app store? Or Apple disallow this kind of app targeting specified customer group to be put in public app store?
If can not put into public store, what is the method to release the app to my customers?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to put it on the App Store as long as it doesn't use private Apple API. If you prefer it not to be on the App Store, you can enroll for Apple's **iOS Enterprise Developer program** which allows ad-hoc distribution (at a costly price $$$). 
Its generally recommended that if the app is for a specific target group and that outside of the group, the app's useless, its better to release as an internal app instead of on the public app store.